# Abelian groups of odd order

Tags: abelian-groups

If G is a finite abelian group of odd order prove that the product of all elements in G is equal to the identity element of G.Well , I can prove this with an example but is there any **general** proof for this?

Comment: You just search "abelian product odd" and the top hit has 27 upvotes and 7 answers for exactly your question. Seriously, you have to stop writing posts that are just problem statements, and you have to stop writing posts when the search feature already shows you there are duplicates. (This is apparently the fifth question in a row you've posed like that.)You are positioning yourself to get truckloads of downvotes and near-instant closures if you continue misusing the site this way.

Answer (score 1):

Simply note that if $a \in G$, with $a \ne 1$, then $a^{-1} \ne a$.

In fact, if $a = a^{-1}$, then $a^{2} = 1$. If $a \ne 1$, [then $a$ has period $2$, which cannot occur in a group of odd order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_theorem_(group_theory)#Applications).

Alternatively, let $P = \prod_{a \in G} a$. Since $a \mapsto a^{-1}$ is a bijection, we have $P = \prod_{a \in G} a^{-1}$. Thus $P^{2} = 1$, as all terms cancel in pairs. By the same argument as above, $P = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $G$ is not the trivial group, where this is trivially true. First, we note that since the order of $G$ is not even, and since the order of each element divides the order of the group, there is no element $a$ such that $a^2=e$.

Then, the product of all elements of $G$ may be rewritten as

$$a_1a_2a_3\ldots a_n = (a_1a_1^{-1})(a_2a_2^{-1})\ldots (a_na_n^{-1}) = e\cdot\ldots\cdot e=e$$

where we simply "pair up" all of the inverses of $G$. *Note that this can be done strictly because $G$ is abelian*.

You should think about whether this is true when $G$ is not a finite group. Can this argument be used in the infinite case? Why or why not? To give an example, consider the group $G=\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I got it.Thanks

Comment: Will same argument not work for infinite abelian groups?

Comment: Try it out! Think about the example where $G=\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Could you please write the example in answer box as I am unable to understand the symbol and notations in comments.

Comment: Done! If you're on mobile, you can tap a comment and find a "Render MathJax" button which should make things a little more intelligible.

Comment: Yes, for infinite abelian case of integers,The product of elements must be one as per my intuition. The reason being for every positive number, there exists an inverse, and as the group is infinite it's order must be odd as apart from zero element, the numbers and their inverse exists in pairs.Well Am I right?

Comment: Close, but what I think you mean is not that the product of all integers is _one_, but that the sum of all integers is the _identity_, in this case $0$.